# How to autofit grid column depending on conent - ExtJS

Tags: extjs

Is there any way to set columns width to match the width of the max length content? I want to make the first column that shows the counter of the row to autosize the width and not style it with `text-overflow: ellipsis;` which seems to be the default behavior.

See below screenshot regarding the first column: [image]

Any idea would be helpful. Also new to ExtJs framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flex config.  It's kinda a weighted value and lets you tell the container how much of the total area you'd like to give that component.

So, say you have 4 columns and you set each flex config to 1, they each get 1/4 of the total width.

Set the first column to flex: 1 and all the other flex: 2.  Or set all the other columns to flex: 1 and the first column to flex: 0.  Just play around with the value until you get the look you want.

Hope this helps.